# how to increase a number by 1 after random seconds using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Is there any way to increase a number by 1 after random seconds.
For example, the base value is 10. So it will change by 1 after a random seconds(ie. 1/2/3/4/5 seconds randomly).

i have tried like this:

```
var startVal = 10;
setInterval(function(){
    var theVal = startVal + 1; 
    startVal = theVal;
}, Math.round(Math.random() * (6000 - 2000)) + 2000);
```

Number is increasing but the time is not random. Please help.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: jQuery itself wouldn't be used for this.  In JavaScript you can increment a number, you can generate a random number, and you can set a delay for an operation.  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Have you tried something with simple functions like `setTimeout()` and `Math.random()` ?

Comment: What is not working with your code exactly?

Comment: Number is increasing but the time is not random @epascarello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the time to change on each iteration, you will need to use setTimeout.

```js
var startVal = 10;
function increase() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var theVal = startVal + 1; 
    startVal = theVal;
    increase();
    console.log(startVal);
  }, Math.round(Math.random() * (6000 - 2000)) + 2000);
}
increase()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example. Will raise the number by one after 0,1 or 2 seconds

```
let number = 10;

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
function addNumber() {
  number++;
  console.log(number)
}
setTimeout(addNumber, getRandomInt(3) * 1000)
```